# When matplotlib plotting live data from csv file, rapidly increasing RAM

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm not a serious programmer just a fan of ideas. I created this script. It draws graph last 60 rows from a log file that receives data from a vacuum sensor via serial connection , but the problem is that this script is rapidly increasing RAM fill. What wrong with it, what I doing wrong?

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import csv

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)


filename = "loggedData.txt"
last_rows = 60

def update(i):
     file_data = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows = 2,  delimiter=",",
          header=None, parse_dates=True, usecols=[0, 1])

     time_data=(file_data[0].tail(last_rows))
     vacuum_data=(file_data[1].tail(last_rows))

#     print(xdata)
#     print(ydata)

#     ax1.clear()
     plt.cla()
     ax1.plot(time_data,vacuum_data)
     fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)
     ax1.set_xlabel('Measurement time')
     ax1.set_ylabel('Vacuum (Torr)')
     plt.yscale('log')
     ax1.grid(which='major', color='#CCCCCC', linestyle='--')
     ax1.grid(which='minor', color='#CCCCCC', linestyle=':')


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=1000)

plt.show()
```

Comment: If `loggeddata.txt` is growing over time, then loading it into memory with `pd.read_csv` will of course take more RAM each time it is called.

Comment: How to reduce this growth, because it grows over a gigabyte in half hour. For me need to draw only the last 60 row from log file.

Comment: You can probably tweak skip_rows to just read data you haven’t plotted yet.  That should lead to a speed savings as well as keep the ram under control

Comment: I dont think this problem is parse file, because if I run script with commented  "ax1.plot(time_data,vacuum_data)"  line, script working good, RAM growing normal speed.

Comment: Don’t clear the axes, just change the Xdata and ydata in the line collection returned by plot.

Comment: May can you lead by example, thanks.